# Mean shift algorithm

Tags: st.statistics

Guys i need some help with the statistics terms used to describe this algorithm,
1. it is non-parametric
2. Mean shift considers feature space as a empirical probability density function
please provide a simple description of these terms or point to an article giving quick   introduction to the statistical concepts used by this algorithm.

Comment: have you considered http://stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Also, if you ask someone to give you a simple description/explanation, then ideally you should give them some indication of what you already know and which parts you are not familiar with. Otherwise you risk answers that are either too technical, or which start from too basic a level